# Getting reference to another thread based on some parameter

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming

I am working on a Java Client/Server Chat application that allows users inside a LAN to chat between them.

In the server application, I have a main class which creates a different thread whenever a client connects to the server. So, basically I keep open a TCP connection with every client running on a separate thread.

I am having a problem with sending messages. When a user sends a new message + the destination for it to the server, the server must find the thread that has the connection with the destination user and send that message to him. How do I do this. I have associated every thread with a user object, so I need to do something like findThreadByUser(user) and after getting the reference just call the method for sending the message. How do i do this?

Here are parts of the ConnectionHandler class which implements Runnable. I want to access the particular instance of the class and more specifically the method `sendToClient(String message)` in the end of it (outside run method). I tried with the HashMap for storing the user and the thread but I cannot get access to the method `sendToClient(String message)`

```
public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

protected Socket socket;
private ServerData serverData;
private User currentUser;
BufferedReader inFromClient;
PrintStream outToClient;
String clientSentence;
String peerIp;
String peerHostName;

public ConnectionHandler(Socket socketToHandle, ServerData serverData) {
    socket = socketToHandle;
    this.serverData = serverData;
    inFromClient = null;
    outToClient = null;
    currentUser = null;

    clientSentence = " ";
}

@Override
public void run() {
peerIp = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
    peerHostName = socket.getInetAddress().getHostName();
    try {
        outToClient = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        /* Create a reading stream to the socket */

        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error creating buffered handles.");
    }

    System.out.println("Handling connection to client at " + peerIp + " --");

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    /* Read client's message through the socket's input buffer */
                    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress() + "-" + peerIp + " broke the connection.");
                    break;
                }
                /* Output to screen the message received by the client */
                System.out.println("Message Received: " + clientSentence);

                List<String> processedClientSentence = ClientMessageProcessor.process(clientSentence);

                if (processedClientSentence.get(0).equals(new String("LOGIN"))) {
                    String result = ServerActions.login(peerIp, peerHostName, processedClientSentence.get(1), serverData);

                    if (result.equals("success")) {
                        currentUser = serverData.getUserByIP(peerIp);
                        outToClient.println("USERS \"" + ServerActions.getUsers(serverData) + "\"");
                    } else {
                        outToClient.println("ERROR \'" + result + "\'");
                    }
                } else if (processedClientSentence.get(0).equals(new String("GETUSERS"))) {
                    outToClient.println("USERS \"" + ServerActions.getUsers(serverData) + "\"");
                } else if (processedClientSentence.get(0).equals(new String("USERINFO"))) {
                } else if (processedClientSentence.get(0).equals(new String("MESSAGE"))) {
                    ServerActions.sendMessage(currentUser/*.getUserName()*/, processedClientSentence.get(1), processedClientSentence.get(2), serverData);
                } else if (processedClientSentence.get(0).equals(new String("LOGOUT"))) {
                } else {
                }

            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r1).start();
}

public void sendToClient(String message) {
    outToClient.println(message);
}
```

}

Comment: Why can't you make a field `Thread` in each `UserObject`?

Comment: why dont you keep a map, user vs corresponding thread, and refer this map to find thread associated with a particular user

Comment: @SubinS So basically you mean to associate user with threads in the Server Data class and then call the thread like this:
`for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) if (t.getId()==id) //send message` ? Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 2):

Store the Client objects in a `HashMap`, `UserName` (which will be unique) as the Key, and the thread associated with it as the Value...`

Comment: If the OP needs the thread just to get the `User`, store the user as the value.

Comment: Can you please see the change that I made to the question. I tried as you said but what I can access are the basic thread methods. However I want to access another method inside the class that implements the thread. I added the whole class and explanations to the question above. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why not send a broadcast and let the correct client accept the message?

Comment: Why? Just because it is a LAN chat doesn't mean you'll never want to use it over multiple subnets (and it certainly doesn't mean that you always want every private message be sent to every client).